# Voltage drop between hot wire and switch return

Tags: switch, light-fixture, voltage

In my bathroom I have one single pole switch for light and one for a fan. When I turn on just the light all 4 LED bulbs are dimmed. Then if I turn on fan or light in a room which is on the same line, lights turn bright in the bathroom. I took down the light switch and measured voltage between the wires. Hot wire <-> light switch return, it's constantly dropping from 118V to 104V. Hot wire <-> fan switch return, it's pretty much stable on 124V. Do you thing that bathroom light fixture is causing this drop or it could be something else?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like there's a wiring error. If this problem began after work had been done on that circuit, please describe the work and show photos of the connections and cables entering the junction boxes so we can help sort out how it can be repaired.

Comment: Go to the kitchen and turn on a big 120V load like a microwave on "defrost" (which cycles on and off).  Anything dramatic happen with the bathroom lights?  By the way, voltage across a switch *that is turned on* should be 0 volts.  The switch shorts the two terminals together when on.

Comment: To me it sounds like a neutral problem. When you turn something on that is on the other leg the lights get bright and that is the critical clue. Having a voltage shift can also be caused from the same thing the other load 120v and this load 120v may be functioning like a 240v load and the bad neutral is the root cause. If it’s only on this circuit make sure all of your neutrals are solidly connected. If you see it on more than this circuit is it on a sub panel? Of all fed from the main and everything is solid call your utility , but if a loose connection this can be the cause.

Comment: Here is the picture: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ddohRRGCWj3Z_pXO0hQnI-A-4W1yYQ7N?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to measure each wire relative to neutral or ground. Is there a voltage from the light return wire (light load) to neutral?

Comment: Light return to neutral - 108.8V. So I tried to  bypass return line, connected "external" wire to the light fixture but it's still the same. Then I turned on light in the next room and bulb was brighter. Turned light off and on again in that room and bulb started flickering and after 10 seconds stabilized but it was dimmed. Something weird is going on...

Comment: Could it be that neutral is touching ground wire somewhere?